# Excel inclui colunas sozinho a partir de um intervalo?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ola, sou nova aqui, mas estou com um probleminha em excel.
Preciso fazer uma tabela que inclua colunas com um numero a partir do nome.
Na tabela base o usuario ira preencher o nome da pessoa e sua pontuação, e preciso que em outra aba, com uma tabela apareça o nome da pessoa e o excel va incluindo o numero que foi preenchido na planilha base a cada coluna.

```
    A      B    C   D
1   JOÃO   2        1
2   JOSE        1   
3   MARIA  3    2   2
4   FRANCISCA       4
```

É possivel isso?

Comment: É só pegar um valor de uma planilha e jogar para outra? Não entendi mt bem

Comment: Mais ai eu teria q fazer manual, teria q ficar filtrando na planilha base o nome da pessoa e pegar a pontuação dela, numero por numero e colocar na tabela resumo.  A planilha base é uma planilha normal, que a pessoa coloca no nome do colaborador, e a pontuação dele (1 a 10) por algum tipo de serviço prestado e na tabela eu ja tenho o nome de todos os colaboradores mas preciso que o excel buque pelo nome da pessoa a pontuação dela inserida na base, numero por numero e acrescente isso a cada coluna

Comment: Ah, agora acho que entendi. Mas o que estaria resumido na tabela resumo com relação a tabela base?

Comment: Apenas o nome da pessoa e todas as pontuações feitas por ela no mês. exemplo: Jose fez 1,3,5,2, Maria 2,4,5 , apenas preciso q ele busque essa informação e coloque nas colunas seguidas na tabela

Comment: Mas se é toda a pontuação então não tem nada resumido, não é mesmo?

Comment: Não, na planilha base esta tudo preenchido manualmente (nome e pontuação), linha por linha, mas a tabela nao apareçe cada pontuação dada a tal nome. Tentei fazer uma dinâmica, mas ela conta ou compacta as  pontuações repetidas, e preciso de numeros, se o cara só receber pontuação 1, preciso que apareça todos esses 1's nas colunas na frente do nome do cara.

Comment: Talvez a solução seja o `PROCV` (ou `VLOOKUP` se seu excel for em inglês). Poderia postar um pequeno exemplo de como seriam essas tabelas?

Comment: Entao, mas o procv, na primeira palavra que ele acha como referencia, ele para de procurar e só tras aquele valor e sempre ira aparecer o nome do colaborador mais de 1 vez na planilha. Desculpe mas, eu posto em um novo tópico?? tem um e-mail para eu ti mandar um exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o recurso de Tabela dinâmica do Excel para isso. Nele você pode transformar esses dados numa matriz onde o nome será a coluna e a pontuação o valor correspondente, esse recurso calcula quase tudo para você.

Nesse [link](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Criar-uma-Tabela-Din%C3%A2mica-para-analisar-dados-da-planilha-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) explica os primeiros passos e acredito que são o suficiente para dar resultado que você precisa.

Comment: Mas a tabela dinâmica ira contar ou compactar os dados e eu preciso que eles apareçam na tabela resumo, numero por numero. exemplo: Jose fez 1,3,5,2, Maria 2,4,5, isso quando seleciono apenas 1 mês especifico, é apenas nome da pessoa na linha e todas as pontuações dela em cada coluna.

Comment: Entendi, ainda usando a tabela dinâmica, você pode colocar as colunas de pontuação na área de linhas da tabela dinâmica, assim ele não irá somar ou contar a informação. Mas isso só dará certo se você puder prever o numero máximo de colunas para pontuação.